# When to add salt to dosa batter?

Tags: salt, fermentation, indian-cuisine

Just wondering when you add salt to dosa batter? I guess it depends on where you live (eg climate) - for example I live in not hot nor cold city, and I would generally add salt after fermentation. I know that in hot places, people would usually add it before so the batter doesn't go bad. Is there any difference in taste if adding before or after?

Comment: Is there a benefit to adding the salt later?

Comment: I am not sure, but there's a benefit in terms of batter consistency/quality if you add it prior.

Comment: So you are saying you get a better consistency if you add it before, but you add it after? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

My belief is that the salt can inhibit the bacteria and yeast growth that is necessary for fermentation, so I add the salt after fermentation and just before cooking.